# Changing method of parameter specification in rails url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, model, controller

In my API, I've implemented the following way of showing a users account in JSON (very simple).

```
class API::V1::UsersController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def show
    respond_with User.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

This is my routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  # Api definition
  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :users, :only => [:show]
    end
  end
end
```

As of now, this works by allowing my to browse to the URL: http://localhost/api/v1/users/1 to show the user account with ID 1.  What I want is to be able to type http://localhost/api/v1/users/show?id=1 to allow for the possibility of specifying more than just the one parameter to the show method.

I've setup a rails application that expects the parameters to be specified in this way in the past but this time around it's not working.  I'm assuming it's something to do with the way I've defined the route in my routes.rb (first time I'm using the resource do notation). Any help would be greatly appreciated. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

Routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  # Api definition
  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
    namespace :v1 do
      #resources :users, :only => [:show]
      get '/users/show/' => 'users#show'
    end
  end
end
```